# Finite extension with order divisible by a prime number

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

> Assume that $K\subset \mathbb{C}$ is a subfield of $\mathbb{C}$. Suppose that $\forall \alpha \in \mathbb{C}$ and $\alpha \notin K$, $p \mid [K(\alpha):K]$ where $p$ is a fixed prime number. Prove that $[K(\alpha):K]$ is a power of $p$ for any $\alpha \in \mathbb{C}$.

The original problem is talking about finite extension with order divisible by a prime number. We reduce it to above case.

Anyone has  some ideas?

Comment: Around here we use "$\$$" to delimit $\LaTeX$.

Comment: What restrictions are put on $m$?

Comment: So I edited your post.  By the way, did you mean to write $mp \mid [K(\alpha):K]$?

Comment: @RobertLewis Oh, I am just starting using the app and didn't find the right way to add a Latex code

Comment: @RobertLewis There is no such a $m$

Comment: This seems false to me.  Let $K = \mathbb{Q}$, and $\alpha = \zeta_7$, where $\zeta_7$ is a primitive $7^\text{th}$ root of unity.  Then $[K(\alpha):K] = 6$, which is neither a power of $2$ nor of $3$, despite the fact that both divide $[K(\alpha):K]$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume for some $\alpha \notin K$, we have $[K(\alpha):K] = p^nm$, where $m>1$ and $p\nmid m$.

Denote $L$ as the Galois closure of $K(\alpha)$ over $K$. Then $L$ is an extension over $K$ such that $L/K$ is Galois. Denote $[L:K]=p^rs$, then $r\geq n$, $s\geq m$, $p\nmid s$. Also denote the Galois group of $L/K$ as $G$.

By Sylow's theorem, $G$ has a subgroup of order $p^r$, denote it as $H$, then the fixed field $L^H$ of $H$ satisfies $[L^H:K] = s>1$. The extension $L^H/K$ has a primitive element, say $\beta$, then $[K(\beta):K] = s$, contradicts to the hypothesis that $p\mid [K(\beta):K]$.

Comment: Brilliant answer, that's exactly what I want.