# Show that the degree of any finite extension of $F$ is a power of $p$

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

> Let $F$ be a field of characteristic zero such that for some prime $p$, every extension $E$ of $F$ with $E\neq F$ has $[E:F]$ divisible by $p$. Show that the degree of any finite extension of $F$ is a power of $p$

My Attempt:
We have $[E:F]=pk$ for some $k$.
Thus $order(Gal(E,F))=pk$.
So from Sylow's theorem, we have a subgroup $H$ such that $|H|=p$ and
index between $Gal(E,F)$and $H$ = $m$
index between $\{e\}$ and $H$ = $p$

So from the Galois correspondance we get a subfield $F\subset K\subset E$ so that
$[E:K]=p$
$[K,F]=k$

Now by considering the given condition for $K$, we get $k=[K,F]=pm$ for some $m$
As $[E:F]=[E:K][K:F]$,
We get $pk=p^2m$,
So can we do it unitil it reaches $p^k\times1?$ If so why?

Also I know that to apply Galois correspondance, the field extension should be both normal and separable. and Characteristic zero implies it is separable.
But Why should that be normal?

Appreciate your help

Comment: You don't know that $E$ is Galois over $F$.  But use your idea on a Galois extension of $E$ over $F$.

Comment: First use that in a field of characteristic 0, any finite extension is simple, then use this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2350136/finite-extension-with-order-divisible-by-a-prime-number

Answer (score 3):

You are mostly on the right track.

**Hint:** You cannot apply the fundamental theorem of Galois theory directly to an arbitrary extension, $E$.

Suppose by way of contradiction, then that there is some proper extension of $F$, $E$, for which $[E:F]$ is not a power of $p$. Then write $[E:F]=p^kn$ where $n$ is chosen to be $\_\_\_\_\_\_$ to $p$.

Let $N$ be the $\_\_\_\_\_$ of $E$. Since $[N:F]=[N:E][E:F]$ is divisible by $\_\_\_\_\_\_$ by Sylow's theorem, there exists a subgroup of $\mathrm{Gal}(N:F)$ of order $\_\_\_\_\_\_$. By the fundamental theorem of Galois theory, this means that there exists a field intermediate $F$ and $N$, $K$, s.t. $[N:K]=|\mathrm{Gal}(N:K)|=\_\_\_\_\_\_$, so $[K:F]=\_\_\_\_\_\_$, a contradiction.

**Full Explanation:**

> The number $n$ is chosen to be coprime to $p$. Since $[E:F]$ is not a power of $p$, $n>1$. $N$ is chosen to be the normal closure of $E$ over $F$. As we are working over a field of characteristic $0$, $N$ is then automatically a Galois extension of $F$. We choose $K$ so that $[N:K]=|\mathrm{Gal}(N:K)|=p^k$. Then $[K:F]=n$ which is not divisible by $p$ even though $n>1$ means that $K$ is a proper extension of $F$, a contradiction.

Comment: I am quite late, maybe still someone reads this. Why would $[K:F]=n$ wouldn't it be rather $[N:F]=[N:K][K:F]=p^k*[K:F]=[N:E][E:F]=p^k*n*[N:E]$, from which it follows that $[K:F]=n*[N:E]$. For the conclusion, however, this does not matter (as for n>1 this would still be a proper extension)

Comment: @dancingqueen you are correct, but I also noticed this mistake quite late and did not want to edit an old answer. To be even more explicit, we should specify that $[N:K]$ may be a larger power of $p$ than $p^k$ chosen via Sylow's theorem, since $[N:F]> [E:F]$, but in the end we still get that $[K:F]$, whatever it is, is coprime to $p$ and divisible by $n$ (hence $>1$).